# How to visualize timeseries output at each epoch in tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I have a keras model that outputs an MxN tensor along with several scalar metrics. The metrics show up just fine in the *SCALARS* and *TIME SERIES* tabs:

[image]

This view is great for visualising scalars where the x-axis is the total number of epochs in my training run.

However, I would like to visualise the MxN tensor output at various epochs as well, e.g. by picking an epoch and viewing the tensor as a plot of N lines on a chart where the X axis is of length M (in my case this would be time).

Can tensorboard facilitate this? If so, how?

I am using tensorflow 2.9.0.

Comment: I think this might be asking for the same thing, but I lack the knowledge of how PR Curves work to implement it: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1110

Comment: And here's a feature request open since 2020 asking my exact question. Damn. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/3121